# CodeIgniter - Is it possible to change the URL when an AJAX action is performed?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have been working on ajax for quite a while. I know about the hashtag and hashbang. Recently  I have started using Code Igniter framework. Lets say I am in a page - http://domain.com/media, and there is a link called 'audio'.

When I click on this audio link, I send an ajax request, fetch the contents and display the content dynamically. But in such case the URL still remains the same (i.e.,) http://domain.com/media.

Now, is it possible to change the url to http://domain.com/media/audio when I click on the audio link and I still want to have the ajax functionality. I dont want to do it the usual way of the code-igniter (/controller/method).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

If it is not possible in Code Igniter, is it possible in any other framework?

Comment: Don't you mean `domain.com/media/#/audio` or `domain.com/media#audio`? The `domain.com/media/audio` looks like an apache rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to achieve this.

[Here's an example of my own site](http://robin.castlin.se/galleri) using it for browsing given images; no reloading occurs. I've also added support for each gallery image and it's loaded url, so that you can share the url with anyone without problems. The fallback is that if `pushState` is not supported, you will simply browse as you always do.